# How to get associate belongsTomany more than 2 table in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have table for show Family Relation of Insurance like this.

PoliciesTable :

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`policy_no` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
.
.
```

ProfilesTable :

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
.
.
```

RelationStatusesTable :

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`status_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
.
.
```

And join table is BeneficiariesTable :

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`policy_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`profile_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`relation_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`insured_percent` float NOT NULL,
```

If I use 'PoliciesTable' is main data.How I can get belongsToMany with 'Profiles' and associate 'RelationStatuses' too?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations

Comment: Are you asking for how to load the associated data, ot how to define the associations? Maybe both?

Comment: I want to load data and define association guide. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using the `bake` utility to generate code for you? Looks like you're following naming standards that it understands, so it should generate a whole bunch of useful code for you, including associations and basic containment in relevant actions.